# SONAR: Upgrade 3.7 to 4.0:Sonar maven analysis failure - java.lang.LinkageError: org/slf4j/Marker

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have recently upgraded SONARQUBE 3.7 to 4.0.

From then on, i am getting the following failure for the Java Project during SONAR analysis.

FYI, There are no significant code changes or dependency changes in the project which might be attributed to this issue.

Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

GOALS FOR JENKINS JOB:
  STEP 1: -Dmaven.test.skip=true -X clean install
  STEP 2: sonar:sonar

Additional Details:

```
SONARQUBE v4.0
JENKINS v1.530
sonar-maven-plugin v2.1
DB: MS SQL SERVER 2008
Project dependencies: SLF4J - v1.7.1
```

Sample log data from Jenkins Job :

```
  [INFO] [17:01:37.375] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://xxx/sonarqube/dashboard/index/com.xxx:project-name
[INFO] [17:01:38.714] Executing post-job class org.sonar.issuesreport.ReportJob
[INFO] [17:01:38.714] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[INFO] [17:01:38.716] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[INFO] [17:01:38.764] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[INFO] [17:01:38.788] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2013-10-24 and 2013-11-20
[INFO] [17:01:38.789] <- Delete snapshot: 2013-11-20T00:05:54-0500 [351284]
[INFO] [17:01:39.102] <- Delete snapshot: 2013-11-20T00:15:43-0500 [351295]
[INFO] [17:01:39.411] <- Delete snapshot: 2013-11-20T11:16:27-0500 [351435]
[INFO] [17:01:39.718] <- Delete snapshot: 2013-11-20T11:25:26-0500 [351446]
[INFO] [17:01:40.021] <- Delete snapshot: 2013-11-20T17:35:15-0500 [351457]
[INFO] [17:01:40.368] <- Delete snapshot: 2013-11-20T19:01:21-0500 [351468]
[INFO] [17:01:41.672] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2012-11-22 and 2013-10-24
[INFO] [17:01:41.673] <- Delete snapshot: 2013-10-24T19:01:55-0400 [287116]
[INFO] [17:01:42.023] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2008-11-27 and 2012-11-22
[INFO] [17:01:42.024] -> Delete data prior to: 2008-11-27
[INFO] [17:01:42.027] -> Clean project-name [id=2845]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) @ order-services ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project-name/workspace/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.0
[INFO] [17:01:42.543] Load batch settings
[INFO] [17:01:44.280] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [17:01:44.284] Install plugins
[INFO] [17:01:44.471] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [17:01:44.478] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx;databaseName=SONAR;SelectMethod=Cursor
[ERROR] Error setting Log implementation.  Cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45.592s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 21 17:01:44 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 51M/930M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) on project order-services: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Error setting Log implementation.  Cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: org/slf4j/Marker -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) on project order-services: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error setting Log implementation.  Cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.sonar.maven.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:37)
    at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:104)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogException: Error setting Log implementation.  Cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.setImplementation(LogFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.useSlf4jLogging(LogFactory.java:78)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.MyBatis.start(MyBatis.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
    at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:173)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.setImplementation(LogFactory.java:114)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: org/slf4j/Marker
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.slf4j.Slf4jImpl.<init>(Slf4jImpl.java:34)
    ... 61 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' marked build as failure
Email was triggered for: Failure
Sending email for trigger: Failure
Sending email to: xx@xx.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Do you have some `slf4j` dependency in your pom.xml ?

Comment: Which version of maven do you use ? Are there Maven extensions declared in your pom file (see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html) ?

Comment: Just some hints regarding to the installation. Are you sure you did everything correct? (
E.g.: 1.) As stated in the Upgrade guide, do not copy-paste the configuration files (conf directory) from the old version. Update the content of the new files instead. 2.): The SQALE plugin has to be manually upgraded to version 2.0 before the SonarQube upgrade. 
3.): The Technical Debt plugin is no longer compatible with SonarQube 4.0. Technical Debt computation is now directly implemented in SonarQube.(you need to uninstall it before updating SonarQube)